# Rolling restart of zetcd causes Flink process to terminate

Tags: apache-flink, apache-curator

I am running zetcd and Flink in containers on AWS Fargate. The zetcd cluster contains three nodes. The deployment strategy is to replaces one node at a time to maintain quorum. Deployments to the zetcd cluster cause Flink processes to die due to failing to connect to Zookeeper.

I observe the following scenario:

- Starting condition: healty zetcd cluster with three nodes, and a healthy Flink cluster.
- When the first zetcd node is deployed, some Flink instances may lose connection to zookeeper if they are talking to this specific zetcd node, but will restore connection to a different healthy zetcd node.
- When the second zetcd node is deployed, same as above.  Further, I observe Flink never tries to connect to newly provisioned zetcd nodes.
- When the last zetcd node is deployed, Flink fails to re-establish connection with zetcd, and the Flink process terminates.
- When all Flink nodes are reprovisioned, the system returns to a healthy state.

I think Flink caches the zetcd nodes on startup, and Flink is not aware of zetcd node replacements. Once all initial zetcd nodes are replaced, Flink cannot connect to zookeeper and dies.

Flink uses Apache Curator; perhaps this behavior is an artifact of how Curator manages connections to Zookeeper?

I appreciate any guidance on how to keep Flink up to date with the current list of zetcd nodes, or if I am entirely wrong in the first place :)

---

Relevant `flink-conf.yaml`

```
high-availability: zookeeper
high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: zetcd-service.local:2181
high-availability.storageDir: s3://flink-state/ha
high-availability.jobmanager.port: 6123
```

Flink loses connection to ZK, and attempts to reconnect.

```
00:42:07.788 [main-SendThread(ip-10-0-59-233.us-west-2.compute.internal:2181)] INFO  org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x79526ef2595a9606, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
00:42:07.888 [main-EventThread] INFO  org.apache.flink.shaded.curator.org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: SUSPENDED
00:42:07.888 [Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService - Connection to ZooKeeper suspended. The contender akka.tcp://flink@10.0.38.41:6123/user/dispatcher no longer participates in the leader election.
00:42:07.888 [Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService - Connection to ZooKeeper suspended. Can no longer retrieve the leader from ZooKeeper.
00:42:07.888 [Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService - Connection to ZooKeeper suspended. Can no longer retrieve the leader from ZooKeeper.
00:42:07.888 [Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService - Connection to ZooKeeper suspended. The contender http://10.0.38.41:8081 no longer participates in the leader election.
00:42:07.888 [Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService - Connection to ZooKeeper suspended. The contender akka.tcp://flink@10.0.38.41:6123/user/resourcemanager no longer participates in the leader election.
00:42:07.889 [Curator-PathChildrenCache-0] DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.ZooKeeperSubmittedJobGraphStore - Received CONNECTION_SUSPENDED event
00:42:07.889 [Curator-PathChildrenCache-0] WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.ZooKeeperSubmittedJobGraphStore - ZooKeeper connection SUSPENDING. Changes to the submitted job graphs are not monitored (temporarily).
00:42:08.820 [main-SendThread(ip-10-0-160-244.us-west-2.compute.internal:2181)] INFO  org.apache.flink.shaded.zookeeper.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server ip-10-0-160-244.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.0.160.244:2181
```

Flink fails to connect to a ZK node, and dies.

```
00:42:22.892 [Curator-Framework-0] ERROR org.apache.flink.shaded.curator.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState - Connection timed out for connection string (zetcd-service.local:2181) and timeout (15000) / elapsed (15004)
org.apache.flink.shaded.curator.org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.checkTimeouts(ConnectionState.java:225) [flink-dist_2.11-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:94) [flink-dist_2.11-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator.org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:117) [flink-dist_2.11-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:835) [flink-dist_2.11-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:809) [flink-dist_2.11-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:64) [flink-dist_2.11-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.curator.org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:267) [flink-dist_2.11-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
```

Comment: Hi @domuro . Did you find any resolution to this. We have been facing the same issue.